# Почему numpy.random.random() в комбинации с np.random.seed() возвращает array из константных чисел?

Tags: python, numpy

начал изучать python и с ним библиотеку numpy и столкнулся ну совсем не понятным для меня результатом работы функции numpy.random.random.

**Ожидаемый результат** - после каждого нового старта, функция генерирует **array из случайных чисел** в диапазоне от 0,0 до 1,0.

**Получаемый результат** - после каждого нового старта, функция генерирует **array из константных чисел** в диапазоне от 0,0 до 1,0. Этот результат верный (согласно книге). В книге, к сожалению, об этом аспекте не сказано не слова и я не понимаю почему.

*Что делает np.random.seed() с numpy.random.random?* Почему numpy.random.random() в комбинации с np.random.seed() возвращает array из константных чисел??? Какой же это random если числа всё время одинаковые?
Без np.random.seed(1) начинает numpy.random.random() работать как я ожидал.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

a = np.random.random((3, 4))
b = np.random.random((3, 4))

print('It is result_a \n', a, '\n')
print('It is result_b \n',  b)
```

Очень хочу понять, что происходит на самом деле. Подскажите пожалуйста!

Читал:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.random.html

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html#numpy.random.RandomState

Comment: https://younglinux.info/python/random

Comment: Когда вы явно указываете один и тот же сид - получаете одну и ту же последовательность псевдослучайных чисел, а когда не указываете - сиду присваивается случайное значение и получаете поэтому случайную ппсч

Comment: Так ведь seed с заданным значением запускает последовательность псевдослучайных чисел с одного и того же места. А при инициализации без параметра место начала выбирается с помощью вспомогательных инструментов (например, показаний таймера)

Comment: https://pyprog.pro/random_sampling_functions/seed.html

Comment: Большое спасибо! 
Понял.